# Modern Perl: how to implement Redispatching Methods in AUTOLOAD()?

Tags: perl, oop

Feeling weak in OO topic i try to get improved with [Modern Perl book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html). About asked topic i found in book following example:

```
package Proxy::Log; 

sub new
{
    my ($class, $proxied) = @_;
    bless \$class, $proxied;
}

sub AUTOLOAD
{
    my ($name) = our $AUTOLOAD =~ /::(\w+)$/;
    Log::method_call( $name, @_ );
    my $self = shift;
    return $$self->$name( @_ );
}
```

Is this code just a scratch or working example?

I don't uderstand, how could i use it, where and what should it log and how should i create an object (what should get to `$proxied`)?

I added just few lines to test it, but got no AUTOLOAD-functionality:

```
package main;

my $tst = Proxy::Log->new();
say $tst->AnyKindOfSub();
```

I hope you could lead me to some working code with it. I thougt i got idea, how closures and AUTOLOAD works, but i am here a little jammed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the example have switched `bless` parameters in `new` of `Proxy::Log`. It probably should be:

```
bless \$proxied, $class;
```

Find below a functional example, as it was probably intended. The proxy class writes the log and then re-dispatch call to target object (`Another` class in example below).

```
package Proxy::Log;

sub new {
    my ($class, $proxied) = @_;
    bless \$proxied, $class;
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
    my ($name) = our $AUTOLOAD =~ /::(\w+)$/;
    warn "$name: @_";
    my $self = shift;
    return $$self->$name( @_ );
}

package Another;

sub new { 
    bless {}, $_[0];
} 

sub AnyKindOfSub {
    warn "Target called\n";
    return "Hello";
};


package main;

my $tst = Proxy::Log->new(Another->new);
say $tst->AnyKindOfSub();
```

Comment: `Log::method_call` made it to me too foggy, now i understand it was a placeholder for some real logging method. I just thougt, it will recursively call AUTOLOAD and did not see any reaseon for that. Thank you, it much clearer for me now!

Answer (score 8):

As `bvr` noticed, you have flipped your arguments to bless in the constructor.  So while that is the immediate problem with your code, an important consideration when writing redispatching methods is to use the `goto &sub` syntax to erase the stack frame of the `AUTOLOAD` call:

```
sub AUTOLOAD
{
    my ($name) = our $AUTOLOAD =~ /::(\w+)$/;
    Log::method_call( $name, @_ );
    my $self = shift;
  # return $$self->$name( @_ );   # instead of this, use the following:
    unshift @_, $$self;           # setup argument list
    goto &{ $$self->can($name) }  # jump to method
}
```

If the redispatched method uses the `caller` builtin for anything (installing methods, localizing variables, `Carp` error reporting...), then this technique will keep `caller` working properly.  Using the original `return $$self->$name(@_)` line would always report that `caller` was the last line of the `AUTOLOAD` sub, which in turn could be the source of hard to find bugs.

If you want to improve the error reporting a bit, you could write the last line as:

```
 goto &{ $$self->can($name) or Carp::croak "no method '$name' on $$self" };
```

Which assumes that the `Carp` package has been loaded.